# PubSub + GCF unreliable?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Not sure what's going on recently but we encounter several issues with PubSub + GCF.

We publish 100K large messages just fine using the Python Client lib. We confirm that with the returned message_id's.

However the subscribed background GCF (Python) does not trigger consistently. For 500 messages or so (no pattern):

1. function executes fully but stdout is not in SD logs. It only shows e.g.

```
  Function execution started
  Function execution took 1634 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

2. function executes partially and crashes anywhere in the code e.g. right after very first print statement

```
   Function execution started
   key:3330275270010019
   Function execution took 54 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

The first issue is a GCF issue (or SD logging ?) as `stdout` should always reflect in SD - see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging

The second case is more worrying as the message is acked even though function crashed - according to the *note at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#sample_code, it should not.

We want to stick to `print()` because SD logs show the `execution_id` context. Using `gcloud logging`, it records the output under generic 'global' resource type so we cannot tie all outputs.

Proper logging has been a long-standing issue with GCF Python but `print()` not working is new.

For PubSub, how is "*successful function execution*" defined ? If this is merely the ability to start/invoke a function, this is (very) misleading and the documentation + sample code should state to **always** deploy with "retry" option.

Ideally though, PubSub should push the message again if the function crashed so that it's not lost.

Has anyone a better experience using an HTTP function subscriber or PubSub Lite ?

**EDIT** - function is a generic chain function but as requested:

```
import base64
import json

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import requests

GCP_PROJECT = os.getenv("GCP_PROJECT")
OUT_TOPIC = f'projects/{GCP_PROJECT}/topics/taxcalcs.out'

session = requests.Session()
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

def process_taxcalcs(event, context):
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')

    parsed = json.loads(pubsub_message)
    print('key:' + parsed['key']) # to count in bq sink
    print('in_message_id:' + context.event_id)

    url = f"http://{event['attributes']['host_port']}/jsoninvoice"
    response = session.post(url, data=pubsub_message)
    print(f'taxcalc_duration:{response.elapsed}')

    attrs = event['attributes']
    future = publisher.publish(OUT_TOPIC, response.json.encode('utf-8'), **attrs)

    print('out_message_id:' + future.result())
    return
```

We have the exact same problem in the next function.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code for your Cloud Function.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn I have added it but don't believe it's relevant

Comment: You should note that a [Pubsub message is sent multiple times only when the subscriber has yet to acknowledge it](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) so you should not be expecting a message to be resent because the Cloud Function crashed. As for the documentation, they are made very minimally only to showcase what the should be expected, but retries would have to be implemented yourself.

As for the logging issues, you might want to open a new Issue Tracker entry to get help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I will close this as there are many issues being logged in the public issuetracker that affect `PubSub` + `Cloud Function`.

The logging (or basic flushing of stdout) in `GCF` is a pretty big one as one can only speculate why a function crashed and it's not always because of user code. A `retry` logic only works for errors caught by the user code.

Also, as I have learnt from GCP support, `PubSub` could get a `429`, `500` or other transient errors back from `GCF`. `PubSub` should resend the message but unfortunately a user cannot see or track these errors hence be certain the internal retry happened. `PubSub` is, currently, very opaque and you cannot track a given `message_id` from publishing to queue (topic), subscription to function.

We have simply given up on PubSub triggered functions, both background and http.

Where we had `client -> PubSub -> background GCF -> PubSub`,

we now have `aiohttp client -> http function -> PubSub`

- we have visibility and control of the calling errors - `backoff` is a great library for that
- we know exactly which requests ("message_id") failed, where and why, and can act upon it